# Regex match everything except a specific character

Tags: regex

I am trying to set up a regex that will match the following:

```
*test*
*t*
*te*
```

But, I do not want it to match:

```
*test**
```

The general rules are:

- Must start with the beginning of the line (`^`) or a whitespace character (`\s`)
- Must have one and only one `*`
- Can match any character
- Must match one more `*`
- Must end with end of the line (`$`) or a whitespace character (`\s`)

I have generated the following regex:

```
(\s|^)\*([^\*].+?[^\*])\*(\s|$)
```

This nearly satisfies my requirements; however, because of the two `[^\*]` groups within the second capturing group, it seems to require that capturing group to be 3 characters or more. `*tes*` matches, but `*t*` and `*te*` do not.

I have three specific questions:

1. Why does the character negation lead to the 3 character limit?
2. Is there a better way to express "any character except" than I have done here?
3. Any thoughts on a better regex to satisfy my requirements?

Comment: FYI don't need to escape the star in char class; ie `[^\*]` is identical to `[^*]`

Comment: What do you mean by "must have one and only one `*`" when `*test*` is a match ( that has two stars)?

Comment: Good call @Bohemian. I think I was trying it in different contexts and in a capturing group, it needed to be escaped. I forgot to remove the escaping when moving it out of the capturing group. I appreciate the nice catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in the regex is an extra `.` in the capturing group

```
[^\*].+?[^\*]
     ^
```

This will match a character except `*` followed by one or more of any characters except newline.

As the character class is repeated twice, you can use `+` quantifier to match one or more characters.

```
(\s|^)\*([^\*]+?)\*(\s|$)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yB0zJ8/3)

---

You can also use non-capturing groups to exclude the extra matches.

```
(?:\s|^)\*([^\*]+?)\*(?:\s|$)
```

[**Demo 2**](https://regex101.com/r/yB0zJ8/4)

Comment: This is awesome. It makes complete sense and I see why I was confused. Thank you so much for the help.